# Issue with Dell Blade running ESX, trying to figure out the issue

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell

Issue with Dell Blade running ESX, trying to figure out the issue. I have attached the BSOD that ESX puts out when the server freezes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually I think that's a PSOD...

Answer (score 9):

You have a dead or dying CPU, chipset or system-board, speak to Dell.

Comment: Spot on prognosis here, methinks.

Comment: +1 bad CPU or socket. I'd remove one CPU, try to reproduce, if that happens, replace it with the removed CPU, if it reproduces again, replace mobo

Comment: Yep, the first line of the error is a dead givaway.

Answer (score 2):

ECC (either "error correction [or correcting] code" or "error checking and correcting") allows data that is being read or transmitted to be checked for errors and, when necessary, corrected on the fly.

The above error indicates the l3 cache that the cpu is using has detected an unrecoverable error...Since your using an opteron cpu and they have integrated l3 cache on the cpu, you most likely have a bad cpu. I would pull the heatsink/verify it is seated correctly and or reseat. If you continue to have issues I would rma.